# RowState of Gridview doesnot point to correct row

Tags: c#, asp.net

check any check box and then click on the "Button1" . in response it will display the id of checked item , but in the following code id is not correct. please tell me what is going wrong in my code, please have a look at the following code.
**test.aspx.cs** is as follows

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public partial class test : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("Aler id are =");
    foreach (GridViewRow row in TaskGridView.Rows)
    {
        if (row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Alternate)
        {

            Response.Write("," +row.Cells[1].Text);// id

         }
    }
    }
}
```

**test.aspx is as follow**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="test.aspx.cs" Inherits="test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>


<script runat="server">

  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
      // Create a new table.
      DataTable taskTable = new DataTable("TaskList");

      // Create the columns.
      taskTable.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
      taskTable.Columns.Add("Description", typeof(string));
      taskTable.Columns.Add("IsComplete", typeof(bool) );

      //Add data to the new table.
      for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
      {
        DataRow tableRow = taskTable.NewRow();
        tableRow["Id"] = i;
        tableRow["Description"] = "Task " + i.ToString();
        tableRow["IsComplete"] = false;            
        taskTable.Rows.Add(tableRow);
      }

      //Persist the table in the Session object.
      Session["TaskTable"] = taskTable;

      //Bind data to the GridView control.
      BindData();
    }

  }

  protected void TaskGridView_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
  {
    TaskGridView.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    //Bind data to the GridView control.
    BindData();
  }

  protected void TaskGridView_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
  {
    //Set the edit index.
    TaskGridView.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    //Bind data to the GridView control.
    BindData();
  }

  protected void TaskGridView_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
  {
    //Reset the edit index.
    TaskGridView.EditIndex = -1;
    //Bind data to the GridView control.
    BindData();
  }

  protected void TaskGridView_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
  {    
    //Retrieve the table from the session object.
    DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["TaskTable"];

    //Update the values.
    GridViewRow row = TaskGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["Id"] = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[1].Controls[0])).Text;
    dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["Description"] = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[2].Controls[0])).Text;
    dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["IsComplete"] = ((CheckBox)(row.Cells[3].Controls[0])).Checked;

    //Reset the edit index.
    TaskGridView.EditIndex = -1;

    //Bind data to the GridView control.
    BindData();
  }

  private void BindData()
  {
    TaskGridView.DataSource = Session["TaskTable"];
    TaskGridView.DataBind();
  }
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>GridView example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />

      <asp:GridView ID="TaskGridView" runat="server" 
        AutoGenerateEditButton="True" 
        AllowPaging="true"
        OnRowEditing="TaskGridView_RowEditing"         
        OnRowCancelingEdit="TaskGridView_RowCancelingEdit" 
        OnRowUpdating="TaskGridView_RowUpdating"
        OnPageIndexChanging="TaskGridView_PageIndexChanging">
      </asp:GridView>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[RowState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.rowstate.aspx) can be a bit-wise combination and you may also need to pay attention to [RowType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.rowtype.aspx) property as you would be only interested in data rows. For example,

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in TaskGridView.Rows)
{
    if ((row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Alternate) == DataControlRowState.Alternate &&
        row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {

       Response.Write("," +row.Cells[1].Text);// id

    }
}
```

Comment: @Abduljalil, what is the output that you get?

Comment: What happens when you simply check for DataRow: if(row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow){ Response.Write("," +row.Cells[1].Text); } ?

Comment: 1,3,5, etc doesnot know why the following condition true

Comment: When you say 'id of checked item', do you mean you want 1) the ID of the CheckBox you clicked? 2) the index of the row? 3) or the ID of your record (tableRow["Id"])?

Comment: @Abduljalil, you are getting the correct output (1,3,5, etc) as per the code written. You are storing loop variable (`i`) value in first cell and getting alternate values. Perhaps, you should tell us what is the expected output or what you want to do exactly?

Answer (score 0):

i have modified code now my problem resolved. now the final code is

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in TaskGridView.Rows)
{
    if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow )
    {
       if(((CheckBox)(row.Cells[1].Controls[1])).Checked)

       Response.Write("," +row.Cells[1].Text);// id

    }
}
```